# How to get number of posts in same category as current post?

Tags: widgets, conditional-tags

I'm using the Widget Logic plugin to dynamically display a recent posts widget.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$postcount = $thiscat->count; 
return
is_single() || is_category() && $postcount > 0;
```

The problem is, if I'm viewing a single post and that post is the only one in its category, the widget is empty with just the title showing.

I need to change the code so it only displays the widget if there's more than one post in the category.

Comment: Could you paste your widget's code into your question?

Comment: @Dan. I've posted an answer to this question already.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work using the following code:

```
global $wp_query;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
$countposts = $postcat[0]->count;
$thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$postcount = $thiscat->count; 
return
is_single() && $countposts > 1 || is_category() && $postcount > 0;
```